# Problems with jQuery in a PhoneGap app

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, mobile-application

Can't seem to get it included. I was using this:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

and then had this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function initialize(){

 $(document).ready(function() {
   $("a").click(function() {
     alert("Hello world!");
   });
 });

}

</script>

....

<body onload="initialize()">
<a href="">Link</a>
</body>
```

But when I click the link, nothing happens. I have no way of knowing whether jQuery is even including properly. I'm completely new to jQuery, so for all I know I'm making an obvious error here, but it's straight from the jQuery beginner guide, so I'd think it was close at least. Anyone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just remove that function. It is useless.

```
$(function(){
    $("a").click(function(){
        alert("Hello world!");
    });
});
```

PS: Your code in work: http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/h4dmF/

Comment: Okay, you are at least semi-correct. It worked when I put the jQuery in a separate script (initialize had been doing other things as well, non-jQuery related; they were irrelevant so I do not show them here, but that's why I have it). But now I'd like to understand why this made a difference. Initialize is called onload. So shouldn't that event trigger be set up correctly  at onload to wait for a click?

Comment: @Aerovistae - Actually, you should not even have this `onload="initialize()"`, and `initialize()` should be placed inside `$(document)`.

Comment: How do I set it up to happen onload if I can't use onload?

Comment: Very close-- I need a series of scripts to be executed when the page first loads. How do you do that with jQuery without using the onload attribute? I see that your example executes properly, but I don't see why. Initialize, the function which creates the event handler for Link, is never called. So when is that event handler added?

Comment: When you use `$(document).ready` (shorthand form: `$()`), it will automatically run when DOM is loaded. And look closely, there is a `()` after the `initialize` function. (`(function initialize(){blah})()`) and actually, if it is not being called again, you can remove `initialize` and left with `(function(){})()`.

Comment: `$()` --> Auto-run when DOM is loaded, so that you don't need `onload`. So yeah, I think it is the trick.

Comment: I see. That being said, why is it necessary to include the first "$(function(){" Why not just say "$(function initialize(){"? What's the point of wrapping it?

Comment: It's because you said you want the `initialize` function. -_- It is pretty much useless in this case: see http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/h4dmF/2/

Comment: I think I comprehend. In essence, "$(function() {  (function initialize() {" is (practically) equal to "$(function(){" is (practically) equal to "$(function initialize(){". Any of those three phrasings will result in the code being executed upon loading of the DOM.

Comment: You can say they are the same in this case.

Comment: Exactly. Thanks very much for the extended help.